# Sorting object by value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I can imagine this has been asked a few times but I literally cannot find an example of a solution to the specific problem I'm trying to figure out.

So I have an object, like so:

```
var collection = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
```

I then have an array, which is the 'order', like so:

```
var order = [2, 0, 1];
```

I want to use the 'order' array to reorder the collection in that specific order. I've been trying quite a few solutions with the .sort function, but I can't find one that fits. Can anyone enlighten me? Probably simple, I'm hoping.

Comment: Not sure what your needs are but in such a simple case you could order by index.

Comment: Be wary of solutions that use multiple, uncached calls to `indexOf`, since they will involve sweeping through `order` many, many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sort()` method to accomplish this using `indexOf`:

```
collection.sort(function(a, b){
    return order.indexOf(a.id) > order.indexOf(b.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` function on the order array in the custom sort function, like this:

```
collection.sort(function(x, y) {
                     return order.indexOf(x.id) > order.indexOf(y.id);
                });
```

Comment: Seems like I need to type faster, @ozk is faster than me :(.

Comment: StackOverflow is all about typing agility :)

Answer (score 1):

seems to be as easy as that:

```
var collection = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
var order = [2, 0, 1];
var sorted = [];
for(var i=0,c=order.length;i<c;i++){
    sorted.push(collection[order[i]]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that does what the OP is asking for. That takes `collection` and uses `order` to say "list the third, then the first, then the second from collection". I think that OP wants "list id:2, then id:0, then id:1"

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
var collection = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
var order = [2, 0, 1];
var sortedCollection = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < order.length; i++ ) 
  sortedCollection.push(collection[order[i]]);
console.log(sortedCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to avoid here is scanning through either of these arrays more than you have to.

Here's one solution that avoids this:

```
/*
 * Map the indexes of the objects in collection to their final location
 */
var sortIndex = {};
order.forEach(function(value, index) {
  sortIndex[value] = index;
});

/*
 * Put the objects in collection into their new, sorted collection
 */
var sortedCollection = [];
collection.forEach(function(value) {
  var sortedLocation = sortIndex[value.id];
   sortedCollection[sortedLocation] = value;

});
```

Thus, we have a single scan through each of the arrays, keeping the work down to a minimum.

I've used `forEach` here as a convenience; you could use a library like Lodash or Underscore, or rewrite this to use explicit iteration over the arrays.